# GRUB2 how to shutdown computer if disk not found with search command

Tags: bootloader, grub2

I'm using the GRUB2 to load Windows To Go with following grub.cfg menu entry:

```
menuentry "MS Windows" --class cl-windows --id id-windows {
    
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root XXXX-XXXX
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

And I want the script to automatically just shutdown the computer if the search command won't found the searched drive. How to modify the script? Thanks.

Comment: go to the BRUB command prompt ... see if there is a shutdown command available

Comment: There is shutdown command (halt), but what to do with it? If I place this command after chainloader, the systems shutdowns even if the searched drive exist.

Comment: You can use an if-statement in grub: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Shell_002dlike-scripting

Comment: Yes, but if... what? I didn't find in manual if search command returns any value, and if search fails, the ${root} variable still has the default value (instead of 0, null or something like that)...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there is the solution to mine question:

```
menuentry "MS Windows" --class cl-windows --id id-windows {
    
    if search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root XXXX-XXXX; then
        chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
    else
        halt
    fi
}
```

...but I'm not sure it is perfectly proper as I wasn't able to find any info about the search command return value (exit status) in GRUB2 manual...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Dear bot, as I wrote: "not sure it is perfectly proper as I wasn't able to find any info about the search command return value (exit status)"...